# Why does an intersection with a discriminated union in a mapped type give a union of all types intead of narrowing it?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have a simple discriminated union like this:

```js
enum Kind {
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = "c"
}

type Value =
    | { kind: Kind.A, value: 1 }
    | { kind: Kind.B, value: 2 }
    | { kind: Kind.C, value: 3 }
```

I want to transform in into an object type where each key in `Kind` would have a corresponding value from `Value["value"]`. For the example above it should look like `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`.

To select a value from a discriminated union I use an intersection with an object with a concrete kind property:

```js
type t1 = (Value & { kind: Kind.A })["value"]
//   ^? type t1 = 1
```

But when I do the same thing inside a mapped type, it spits out `Value["value"]` instead:

```js
type t2 = { [K in Kind]: (Value & { kind: K })["value"] }
//   ^? type t2 = { a: 1 | 2 | 3, b: 1 | 2 | 3, c: 1 | 2 | 3 }
```

What am I missing here?

Here's a working solution to my problem:

```js
type t3 = { [K in Kind]: (Value & { kind: K }) }

// This almost works, the main problem has magically disappeared by doing this in two iterations instead of one
// But now TS says that "value" cannot be used to index t3[K]
type t4 = { [K in Kind]: t3[K]["value"] }

// Actually works
type t5 = { [K in Kind]: t3[K] extends infer T extends { value: unknown } ? T["value"] : never }
```

Also solved the indexing issue by merging the intersection first:

```js
type Merge<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }

type t6 = { [K in Kind]: Merge<Value & { kind: K }> }
type t7 = { [K in Kind]: t6[K]["value"] }
```

---

I've narrowed the issue down to the following:

```js
enum Kind {
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = "c"
}

type Value =
    | { kind: Kind.A, value: 1 }
    | { kind: Kind.B, value: 2 }
    | { kind: Kind.C, value: 3 }


type t1 = Kind.A extends infer K extends Kind.A ? (Value & { kind: K })["value"] : never
//   ^? type t1 = 1 | 2 | 3

type t2 = (Value & { kind: Kind.A })["value"]
//   ^? type t2 = 1
```

Apparently TS treats Kind.A differently if it's a type parameter (even if it has an equivalent constraint as in the example above).

Why is this?

[TS Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gliAJlA3gWAFBW1AglAXigCIBDYgGkxygCFCSAjS6nAYQeIGNjMBfTJgAuATwAOwKADVSAGzCSCrbAB9UUANYJEALljaAdLgpQAbnIV6AjFAFYcalJu174SA7RPn5wPQCZbZShHZyRXQzYvC18oAGZAjGFxSSEABgYAChkfKAAydS0w-Xd8PgBKTAB6SpwAPQB%20QQxRCSghGyI0gG1ibwViAF0qmuwGppaUgKIs6LyCl2LEI1synr7gQeG6xsTdibb4ojcl-GAADyFQRABnKAQAM2AAJ1goeqgZnPynQt1X8qgehAwFMzy2ox2SVaQgALAwhLE1tFNhhqttxsk2gBWBjHZbnS5IW4PZ6vd6fBRzH4LGArJE%20QaAqDA0FPcFQMYYIA)

Comment: It's a TS design limitation described at [ms/TS#45428](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45428). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It does, thank you. An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#45428](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45428).

The problem with [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) type like `(Value & { kind: K })["value"]` is that the compiler doesn't realize that it should consult `{kind: K}` at all when figuring out the `value` property type, since `{kind: K}` doesn't have a `value` property.

Given a type like `(A & B)[P]` where `P` extends `keyof A` but not `keyof B` (and where `A & B` isn't immediately evaluated already) the compiler will take the shortcut of just evaluating it as `A[P]`.  This is almost always the right thing to do, but you've found a situation where it isn't.  Or at least where it's not clearly correct.

What would you say `{foo: never, bar: 2}["bar"]}` should be?  It seems like it should be `2`, but what if there is a rule that collapses `{foo: never, bar: 2}` to `never` because it cannot exist?  Then maybe it should be `(never)["bar"]` which is `never`.  It's arguable that it could be either `2` or `never` depending on when the collapsing rule is supposed to apply.  Your case is equivalent to this, just with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these types: `({foo: "a", bar: 1) | {foo: never, bar: 2})["bar"])` could either be `1 | 2` or just `1` depending on when the collapsing rule applies.

But even if we decide that it should be `never` or `1`, the compiler doesn't bother to figure this out, because to do so would make evaluating types more expensive all the time, for only the occasional improvement to correctness.  So it's a design limitation of TypeScript.  The workaround is to use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) as described in the GitHub issue and the other answer to the question.

Comment: In case of `(({ foo: 'a', bar: 1 } | { foo: 'b', bar: 2 }) & { foo: 'a' })['bar']` it returns `1`, so TS doesn't take a shortcut there unless `foo` is a type parameter?

Comment: It depends on when the collapsing rule applies.  Indeed `{foo: 'b', bar: 2} & {foo: 'a'}` is collapsed to `never` before the indexing takes place, but if you have `{foo: K, bar: 2} & {foo: 'a'}`, then any collapsing would have to wait until `K` were specified, which apparently happens after the indexing takes place.

Comment: `(({ foo: 'a', bar: 1 } | T) & { foo: 'a' })['bar']` (where `T` is a similar union member) is also collapsed early, but it breaks indexing for `bar`, which seems even stranger to me. Are these some fine-grained optimization tricks in the compiler?

Comment: Intersections of unions are almost always reduced to unions of intersections.  As for the details of *when* that happens, ‍♂️.

Answer (score 1):

The type utility [`Extract<Type, Union>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) can be of use here:

> Constructs a type by extracting from `Type` all union members that are assignable to `Union`.
>
> [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgDFAvFAogD2AJwIYGNgA8ARNkVAD5REBGZlRuRANFaRVQGZEB8A3AFAB6QVFFQAegH5+oSLACMSVBhz4CAZywBLAHYBzdjoCuAW2oRM7ABRWAlEm5QAbgHstAE1ssAYkZ34tFx0+IRExKSA)
>
> ```ts
> type T0 = Extract<"a" | "b" | "c", "a" | "f">;
> //    ^? type T0 = "a"
> type T1 = Extract<string | number | (() => void), Function>;
> //    ^? type T1 = () => void
> ```

---

It can be applied to your example like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=33#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gliAJlA3gKClAglAvFAIgEMCAaDKAIT0ICMyKBhGggYwYF800AXATwAOwKADUiAGzDDcFAD6ooAawSIAXLBUA6LAG4oANwlT1ARj1dM8lEpXr4STZT2HJwdQCZzchcqR2tjM5GblAAzOY63PxCGkhirgCyRAI01gDaMFAIsYgAuuoAogAePABORKw8ADzxUqQ+trBQHAB8aQQuUgS5zZGYUAD0AwB6APxoQA)

```ts
enum Kind {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
  C = "c",
}

type Value =
  | { kind: Kind.A; value: 1; }
  | { kind: Kind.B; value: 2; }
  | { kind: Kind.C; value: 3; };

type KindValueMap = { [K in Kind]: Extract<Value, { kind: K }>["value"] };
   //^? type KindValueMap = { a: 1; b: 2; c: 3; }
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a mapped type from each union member, since each has all of the information needed:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gliAJlA3gKClAglAvFAIgEMCAaDKAIT0ICMyKBhGggYwYF800AXATwAOwKADUiAGzDDcFAD6ooAawSIAXLBUA6LAG4oANwlT1ARj1dM8lEpXr4STZT2HJwdQCZzchcqR2tjM5GblAAzOY63PxCGkhirgCyRAI01gDaIlAIosFQRADOomkEvogEALrl6iLFLlIVUByRmFAA9K0AegD8aEA)

```ts
type KindValueMap = { [V in Value as V["kind"]]: V["value"] };
   //^? type KindValueMap = { a: 1; b: 2; c: 3; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The main question here is why `(Value & { kind: K })["value"]` behaves differently in given contexts. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767183/why-does-an-intersection-with-a-discriminated-union-in-a-mapped-type-give-a-unio/75767353#comment133656281_75767353) @sailybra I don't have more to add beyond the info at the GitHub issue that jcalz linked in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767183/why-does-an-intersection-with-a-discriminated-union-in-a-mapped-type-give-a-unio/75767353#comment133657606_75767183).